# Instagram Basic Display API returning a NULL username

Tags: php, html, instagram, instagram-api

I have a web platform that must allow users to connect their Instagram profile using the API.
The authentication process **worked** as long as the app was in **development mode**. Since Facebook approved it the process returns NULL as username.

This is the first call to `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize`:

```html
<input type="text" name="client_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="redirect_uri" value="https://www.XXXXXXXX.it/connect.php" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="scope" value="user_profile" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="response_type" value="code" style="display: none;">
```

Then withthe obtained code I call `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token`:

```php
$fields = array(
    'client_id'     => 'XXXX',
    'client_secret' => 'XXXXX',
    'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri'  => 'https://www.XXXX.it/connect.php',
    'code'          => $_GET['code']
);
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($result);
```

Finally, call `https://graph.instagram.com/` with:

```php
$chA = curl_init();
$optArrayA = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.instagram.com/' . $result->user_id . '?fields=username&access_token=' . $result->access_token,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);
curl_setopt_array($chA, $optArrayA);
$resultA = curl_exec($chA);
curl_close($chA);
$resultA = json_decode($resultA);
$usernameU = $resultA->username;
```

The result of these calls was correct before Facebook app approvation, but now returns NULL.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked what the actual API response was?

Comment: @CBroe It seems that the first cURL request in PHP `$ch = curl_init();` is not working, because the HTML Form response is correct. First PHP cURL `$result ;` is empty

Comment: _When_ is it empty - before or after you tried to decode it as JSON? Check what response you got from the HTTP request, _before_ you try to decode it as JSON.

Comment: After some debugging I found that the first PHP call returns `{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "This authorization code has been used"}`, because the first call return always the same code.
Just read that IG tokens are valids for 1h... Are they generated new every hour?